# Word/Riddle Dictionary Part #1

Tags: riddle, word

Maybe I will create a Word/Riddle Dictionary tag when I get enough reputation points...

**Each answer is one word.  Each word begins with the letter shown.**

Your perspective from my point of view?  **A__________**

Object for treating the witness like that?  **B___________**

The name of my dog with no legs?  **C___________**

When in the sink he makes a certain tap?  **D__________**

Can’t get it out without putting it in?  **E__________**

What the wind shrieks to the leaves that time of the year?  **F__________**

Hint:

> The words are related only in the sense that they are in alphabetical order.  Each word is the answer to the riddle on that line.  The letter shown is the first letter of the answer word

Comment: are these words related in any way?

Comment: WHAT would a dog still have even if he had no legs?  WHAT other thing would have those things?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *Your perspective from my point of view?* **Attitude**
>  *Object for treating the witness like that?* **Badgering** (as in, I object, because the other counsel is badgering the witness)
>  *The name of my dog with no legs?* **Cigarette** (because you can take him out for a drag)
>  *When in the sink he makes a certain tap?* **Dancer** (specifically, a Tap Dancer)
>  *Can’t get it out without putting it in?* **Energy** (first law of thermodynamics)
>  *What the wind shrieks to the leaves that time of the year?* **Fall**

Comment: you got 4 of them....i dont want to ruin it for others

Comment: think about a word similar in meaning to perspective that starts with an 'A'

Comment: I hate for these things to just drag out endlessly so I am going to give you the check mark.  Consider Aspect as the first word...

Answer (score 1):

Well, partial answer to start...

> A s p e c t
>  B_______
>  Chi Chi (refer  https://www.google.co.in/amp/m.scmp.com/news/asia/east-asia/article/1924489/chi-chi-dog-no-legs-leaves-south-korea-new-life-and-limbs%3famp=1)
>  D______
>  E f f o r t
>  F l u t t e r

Comment: Maybe. I would **never** have gotten the dog, as I was looking for some horrible pun. Still . . . I'm not so sure on that wind/leaves thing. I think I'd go with a word that is a command **and** a time of year. The sink one . . .? Maybe look for adding something that makes a tapping sound, and add to D to get something in a sink. The rest leave me puzzled, but **those** two are words with the first letter included, **and** comeplete words in the blanks . . . could **that** be the pattern for solving the rest? (Not if "ChiChi" is correct, but elsewise . . . ?)

Comment: @Rob, I meant I do not know the answers for those two words (starting with B and D) and hence kept them as blanks. It is not a strict practise to follow, though.

Comment: @Rob the letter on the blank is the first letter of the answer word...